# React Native Action Button - Unable to Add buttons Dynamically

Tags: react-native, render, floating-action-button, action-button

Unable to Add ActionButton Items dynamically.

I have the following setup --

```
<ActionButton>
    <ActionButton.item name={constant_btn1} />
    <ActionButton.item name={constant_btn2} />
</ActionButton>
```

I want to add dynamic buttons to this list. (The list is received from backend)

I have created a function that returns me views of these buttons.

```
getDynamicBtns() {
    return dynamicButtonsList.map(item, key) => {(
        return <ActionButton.item name={item.btnName} />;
    )};
}
```

and I have used it in this way -->

```
<ActionButton>
    <ActionButton.item name={constant_btn1} />
    <ActionButton.item name={constant_btn2} />
    {this.getDynamicBtns()}
</ActionButton>
```

So this is **rendering my constant buttons**, but **not the dynamic buttons**.

EDIT - 
I am returning the map from the `getDynamicBtns()` function and calling invoking the function call too from within render(). This is just some simplified sample code that I have wriiten.

EDIT2 - 
To prevent any confusion, changing original question's code.

Comment: try to `console.log` the `dynamicButtonsList` array to check if it's not empty

Comment: @zb22 Thanks a lot! 
After checking I got to know that the children of <ActionButton> were a bit incorrect. I’ll post an answer to explain it better.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
The problem was that the .map function returns an array of Objects.

So the final element that was going to be rendered was a React element `ActionButton`.

The ActionButton had only 3 children, irrespective of the size of my dynamic list.

```
ActionButton.children: [
    staticButton1,
    staticButton2,
    [dynamicButton1, dynamicButton2, dynamicButton3, ....]
];
```

As a solution, I took them into separate lists and found a union of the lists.
And then rendered the list inside `<ActionButton>`

Something like this ->

```
let listA = [<ActionButton.Item name='staticBtn1.name' />];

let listB = this.getDynamicBtns();

let finalList = _.union(listA, listB);
```

And then rendered it as -->

```
<ActionButton>
    {finalList}
</ActionButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are no returning anything in getDynamicBtns function. You should return the result of your map:

```
getDynamicBtns() {
    return dynamicButtonsList.map(item => <ActionButton.item name={item.btnName} />)
}
```

Comment: Sorry @Ariel Perez. I am doing that. Have not added it in the question. Will Update.
But this does not solve the problem.